# How to drop previous records on Android SQLite database only after inserting some new ones

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm building an Android app that scraps through the contents of a HTML page (school's website doesn't give us an official app and there's no public API).

I wasn't able to determine whether the data is absolutely new or not, so currently all the fetching data and inserting it in the database is done in an AsyncTask that basically does something like this:

- recreateDatabase() // Drop all tables and create them again.
- insertSubjectList() // goes through all the items in the list and adds them to the database

Then in the AsyncTask result:

- refreshCurrentFragment();

The problem is: if the user goes to an area in the app that reads data from the database between recreateDatabase() and insertSubjectList(), there might be little or no data at all in the database, since it is currently being repopulated.

It doesn't crash the app or so, but it is an undesirable behavior. My question is: is it possible to tell SQLite to only clean the old data after the new one is available to be used in the queries? Old and new cannot be read at they same time since their info might collapse.

Hope someone can help me through this!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like instead of :-

- recreateDatabase() // Drop all tables and create them again.
- insertSubjectList() // goes through all the items in the list and adds them to the database

You want

- insertSubjectList() into a transitional tables (tables with a different name to their counterpart e.g. newly created table)
- rename original tables to another table name e.g. using `ALTER TABLE original TO original_renamed`
- rename the transitional tables to their counterparts (original) table names.
- drop the old tables.

Thus the original tables will still exist whilst the data is being loaded and then for only a relatively short period will no data be available.

This could also be done within a transaction, which would likely improve the performance.

Thus this would answer **YES** to

> is it possible to tell SQLite to only clean the old data after the new
>   one is available to be used in the queries?

And as for

> Old and new cannot be read at they same time since their info might
>   collapse.

They wouldn;t be read at the same time.

For example consider the following demonstration:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master (mydata TEXT);

-- Load the original table with some data 
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cte1 where x < 1000)
INSERT INTO master SELECT * FROM cte1;
SELECT * FROM master LIMIT 10;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- Load the new data (original table still available)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transitional (mydata TEXT);
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(x) AS (SELECT 2000 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cte1 where x < 3000)
INSERT INTO transitional SELECT * FROM cte1;
SELECT * FROM transitional LIMIT 10;

-- Switch the tables - original not available
ALTER TABLE master RENAME TO master_old;
ALTER TABLE transitional RENAME TO master;
-- original now available

-- Clean-up old
DROP TABLE master_old;
END TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM master LIMIT 10;
```

## Android Demo

The following is the code for a working Android example that is similar to the above.

The are 2 pieces of code the invoking activity and the database helper

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Instantiate the helper noting that data will be loaded
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this); 
        // Get the current data
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getFirst10Rows();
        // Write the current data to the log
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);

        //<<<<<<<<<< do the switch >>>>>>>>>>
        mDBHlpr.switchData(DBHelper.TABLE_MASTER);

        //Again get the data and write to the log
        csr = mDBHlpr.getFirst10Rows();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);

        //Clean up
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

### DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    private static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_MASTER = "master";
    public static final String COl_MASTER_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_MASTER_MYDATA = "mydata";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    //Construct the helper NOTE will create the db if needed
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME,null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase(); // force db open
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(create_table_sql(TABLE_MASTER));
        mDB = db;
        addLotsOfData(TABLE_MASTER,1000,1); // Load some data
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Generate the table SQL according to the table name passed
    private String create_table_sql(String table) {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table + "(" +
                COl_MASTER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_MASTER_MYDATA + " TEXT" +
                ")";
    }

    // Switch the original table for a newly created version
    public void switchData(String table) {

        String transitional_table = "transitional";
        String renamed_master = table + "_old";
        boolean already_in_transaction = mDB.inTransaction();

        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
        }

        //<<<<<<<<<< create and load of new data could be done elsewhere
        mDB.execSQL(create_table_sql(transitional_table));
        addLotsOfData(transitional_table,1000,3001); //<<<<<<<< load new data here
        //>>>>>>>>>>

        mDB.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_MASTER + " RENAME TO " + renamed_master);
        mDB.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + transitional_table + " RENAME TO " + TABLE_MASTER);
        mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + renamed_master);

        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDB.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    // Add some data
    private void addLotsOfData(String table, int rows, int value_offset) {
        boolean already_in_transaction = mDB.inTransaction();
        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            addRow(table,String.valueOf(value_offset + i));
        }
        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDB.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    // Insert a single row
    public long addRow(String table, String value) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_MASTER_MYDATA,value);
        return mDB.insert(table,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getFirst10Rows() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_MASTER,null,null,null,null,null,null,"10");
    }
}
```

- Note the above is designed to be run just once, for subsequent runs the before and after data would be the same.

### Result

The log shows (as expected):-

```
04-26 08:42:43.556I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@11697ce
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 0 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=1
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=1
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 1 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=2
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=2
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 2 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=3
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=3
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 3 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=4
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=4
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 4 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=5
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=5
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 5 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=6
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=6
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 6 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=7
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=7
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 7 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=8
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=8
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 8 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=9
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=9
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: 9 {
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    _id=10
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out:    mydata=10
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.557I/System.out: <<<<<
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@3396ef
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out: 0 {
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out:    _id=1
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out:    mydata=3001
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out: 1 {
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out:    _id=2
04-26 08:42:43.652I/System.out:    mydata=3002
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: 2 {
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    _id=3
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    mydata=3003
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: 3 {
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    _id=4
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    mydata=3004
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: 4 {
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    _id=5
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    mydata=3005
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: 5 {
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    _id=6
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    mydata=3006
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: 6 {
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    _id=7
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    mydata=3007
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: 7 {
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    _id=8
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    mydata=3008
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: 8 {
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    _id=9
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out:    mydata=3009
04-26 08:42:43.653I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.654I/System.out: 9 {
04-26 08:42:43.654I/System.out:    _id=10
04-26 08:42:43.654I/System.out:    mydata=3010
04-26 08:42:43.654I/System.out: }
04-26 08:42:43.654I/System.out: <<<<<
```

## Additional

Here's a more versatile approach that would cope with processing multiple tables, bar the obviously App/table specific loading of the new data to the transition tables.

Logging has been added, this enables timings.

- For example running this and loading 10,000 rows *(using `mDBHlpr.addLotsOfData(DBHelper.TABLE_MASTER + DBHelper.TRANSITION_SUFFIX,100000,10000);`)*. It can be seen that:-
- Even though the table takes 0.659 seconds to load the data (10,000 rows), the tables are actually only not available for 0.007 seconds (if the DROP was done after the switch, then 0.001 seconds (dropping tables can be expensive time wise, whilst renaming a table takes little time)).

The amended activity is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Instantiate the helper noting that data will be loaded
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        // Get the current data
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getFirst10Rows();
        // Write the current data to the log
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);

        //<<<<<<<<<< do the switch >>>>>>>>>>
        mDBHlpr.switchData(DBHelper.TABLE_MASTER);

        //Again get the data and write to the log
        csr = mDBHlpr.getFirst10Rows();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);

        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< AutoSwitch example >>>>>>>>>>
        //Create the transition tables
        mDBHlpr.prepareSwitchAllAppTables();

        Log.d("NEWDATALOADSTART","Loading of new data has started");
        // Prepare the new data by loading the data into the transition table
        // (only the 1 table for demo)
        // but perhaps 1 load per table according to requirements
        mDBHlpr.addLotsOfData(DBHelper.TABLE_MASTER + DBHelper.TRANSITION_SUFFIX,100000,10000);

        Log.d("TABLESNOTAVAILABLE","Tables will now be unavailable whil switching");

        // Switch all of the tables
        mDBHlpr.doSwitchAllAppTables();
        Log.d("TABLESAVAILABLE","Switch completed, Tables are now available with new data");

        //Again get the data and write to the log
        csr = mDBHlpr.getFirst10Rows();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);

        //Clean up
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

- i.e. from line `//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< AutoSwitch example >>>>>>>>>>` has been added except for `csr.close()` which is still the last line.
- see comments
- The switch has been split into 2 stages preparation (creation of the transition tables) and the actual switch (rename original tables then rename transition tables to the respective original). Although the switch includes the dropping of the renamed table, this could be moved to a third stage, further reducing the time that the tables are not available.

and the modified **DBHelpr.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    private static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_MASTER = "master";
    public static final String COl_MASTER_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_MASTER_MYDATA = "mydata";

    public static final String TRANSITION_SUFFIX = "_trn";
    public static final String RENAME_SUFFIX = "rename";

    private static final String SQLITE_MASTER = "sqlite_master";
    private static final String SQLITE_MASTER_TYPECOLUMN = "type";
    private static final String SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN = "name";
    private static final String SQLITE_MASTER_SQLCOLUMN = "sql";
    private static final String[] SQLITE_MATSER_COLUMNS = new String[]{SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN,SQLITE_MASTER_SQLCOLUMN};
    private static final String APPTABLES_WHERECLAUSE =
            "(" +
                    SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN + " NOT LIKE 'sqlite%' " +
                    " AND " +  SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN + " NOT LIKE 'android%' " +
                    " AND " + SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN + " NOT LIKE '%" + TRANSITION_SUFFIX + "'" +
                    ")" +
                    " AND " + SQLITE_MASTER_TYPECOLUMN + "= '"  + "table" + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    //Construct the helper NOTE will create the db if needed
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME,null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase(); // force db open
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(create_table_sql(TABLE_MASTER));
        mDB = db;
        addLotsOfData(TABLE_MASTER,1000,1); // Load some data
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Generate the table SQL according to the table name passed
    private String create_table_sql(String table) {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table + "(" +
                COl_MASTER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_MASTER_MYDATA + " TEXT" +
                ")";
    }

    // Switch the original table for a newly created version
    public void switchData(String table) {

        String transitional_table = "transitional";
        String renamed_master = table + "_old";
        boolean already_in_transaction = mDB.inTransaction();

        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
        }

        //<<<<<<<<<< create and load of new data could be done elsewhere
        mDB.execSQL(create_table_sql(transitional_table));
        addLotsOfData(transitional_table,1000,3001); //<<<<<<<< load new data here
        //>>>>>>>>>>

        mDB.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_MASTER + " RENAME TO " + renamed_master);
        mDB.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + transitional_table + " RENAME TO " + TABLE_MASTER);
        mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + renamed_master);

        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDB.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    // Add some data
    public void addLotsOfData(String table, int rows, int value_offset) {
        boolean already_in_transaction = mDB.inTransaction();
        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            addRow(table,String.valueOf(value_offset + i));
        }
        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDB.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    // Insert a single row
    public long addRow(String table, String value) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_MASTER_MYDATA,value);
        return mDB.insert(table,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getFirst10Rows() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_MASTER,null,null,null,null,null,null,"10");
    }

    /**
     * Create transition copy of all App tables (not sqlite..... tables or android.... tables)
     */
    public void prepareSwitchAllAppTables() {
        boolean already_in_transaction = mDB.inTransaction();
        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
        }

        Cursor csr = mDB.query(SQLITE_MASTER,SQLITE_MATSER_COLUMNS,APPTABLES_WHERECLAUSE,null,null, null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String original_tablename = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN));
            String original_sql = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITE_MASTER_SQLCOLUMN));
            String transition_tablename = original_tablename + TRANSITION_SUFFIX;
            String transition_sql = original_sql.replace(original_tablename,transition_tablename).replace("CREATE TABLE","CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS");
            Log.d("PREAPRE4SWITCH","Executing the SQL (create transition table for table " + original_sql +
                    ") \n\t" + transition_sql);
            mDB.execSQL(transition_sql);
            mDB.delete(transition_tablename,null,null); // just to make sure that all transition tables are empty
        }
        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDB.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    public void doSwitchAllAppTables() {

        boolean already_in_transaction = mDB.inTransaction();
        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
        }
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(SQLITE_MASTER,SQLITE_MATSER_COLUMNS,APPTABLES_WHERECLAUSE,null,null, null,null);
        ArrayList<String> tables_to_delete = new ArrayList<>();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {

            String original_name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN));
            String transition_name = original_name + TRANSITION_SUFFIX;
            String rename_name = RENAME_SUFFIX;
            tables_to_delete.add(rename_name);

            Log.d("SWITCHRENAMEORIG","Executing the SQL to rename(original) " + original_name + " table to " + rename_name);
            mDB.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + original_name + " RENAME TO " + rename_name);
            Log.d("SWITCHRENAMETRNS","Executing the SQL to rename(transition) from " + transition_name +
                    " to (original)" + original_name);
            mDB.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + transition_name + " RENAME TO " + original_name);
        }
        csr.close();
        for (String table_to_delete: tables_to_delete) {
            Log.d("SWITCHDROPRENAMED","Dropping renamed original table " + table_to_delete);
            mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE If EXISTS " + table_to_delete);
        }

        if (!already_in_transaction) {
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDB.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

- This assumes that you never create App tables that start with **android** or **sqlite**

  - (sqlite_ is protected as per

    > *Table names that begin with "sqlite_" are reserved for internal use. It is an error to attempt to create a table with a name that starts with "sqlite_".*).
  - So really `SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN + " NOT LIKE 'sqlite%' "` should be `SQLITE_MASTER_NAMECOLUMN + " NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' "`.
- sqlite_master is used to drive the process, it is the schema and contains a list of the tables (and other entities such as indexes, views and triggers).
- Note the above could not be relied upon should FOREIGN KEYS be used and ON CASCADE DELETE were not used. As child tables would then have to be dropped before parents.
- Triggers see [ALTER TABLE - ALTER TABLE RENAME](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

### Result

running the above results in the log including :-

```
...........
04-26 13:41:36.000 I/System.out:    mydata=3010
04-26 13:41:36.000 I/System.out: }
04-26 13:41:36.000 I/System.out: <<<<<



04-26 13:41:36.000 D/PREAPRE4SWITCH: Executing the SQL (create transition table for table CREATE TABLE "master"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,mydata TEXT)) 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "master_trn"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,mydata TEXT)
04-26 13:41:36.007 D/NEWDATALOADSTART: Loading of new data has started
04-26 13:41:43.666 D/TABLESNOTAVAILABLE: Tables will now be unavailable whil switching
04-26 13:41:43.666 D/SWITCHRENAMEORIG: Executing the SQL to rename(original) master table to rename
04-26 13:41:43.667 D/SWITCHRENAMETRNS: Executing the SQL to rename(transition) from master_trn to (original)master
04-26 13:41:43.667 D/SWITCHDROPRENAMED: Dropping renamed original table rename
04-26 13:41:43.673 D/TABLESAVAILABLE: Switch completed, Tables are now available with new data
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9ce45fc
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out: 0 {
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out:    _id=1
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out:    mydata=10000
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out: }
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out: 1 {
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out:    _id=2
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out:    mydata=10001
04-26 13:41:43.673 I/System.out: 
..........
```

## Lastly

You may be interested in :-

> [WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

In which case you could turn WAL on (Android 9+ it is turned on by default) by using [enableWriteAheadLogging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#enableWriteAheadLogging()) (override the **onConfigure()** method to use this).

Comment: Thanks, that works tremendously well!

I'm only worried about the transaction part. After calling the update method, I immediately have to refresh the current fragment, which pulls some data from the database. Since there's nothing more happening in the db during upgrade,  db.inTransaction() will probably return false and the transaction part will be executed. What happens if I call db.endTransaction(), the transactions starts and before it's over somewhere else in my code (during refresh fragment) I query some data?

Comment: Is it possible that some database locked problems might occur? If i turn WAL on this worries shall disappear?

Comment: Unless you are using multiple connections (SQLiteOpenHelper maintains a single connection) then locking should not be an issue. I'd suggest turning WAL on as then you know that what you've developed will be relatively good for the future e.g. for Android 9+ (Pie) devices. WAL has been available since HoneyComb.